# How to make a conditional show and hide modal to my on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem to my show and hide modal,So when i click the input number inside of table data the why the modal still showing, I have a function which when i change the value of input number , the modal will hide.

So here below, I will show you the codes I have,

**First I have append function to append all data inside of table**

```
$('#edit_chainingBuild').append("<tr class='clickable-row'><td>" + Qty + "</td><td class='clickable-row-condiments'>" + Condiments + "</td><td>" + Price + "</td><td style='display:none;' data-attribute-chain-id="+menu_builder_details_id +" class='data-attribute-chain-id'>"+menu_builder_details_id+"</td></tr>");
```

**Now Second when i click each table row, modal  will show,**

```
    $('#edit_chainingBuild').on('click','tr.clickable-row',function(e){

      $('table#edit_chainingBuild tr').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');

      var find_each_id_will_update = $(this).find('.data-attribute-chain-id').attr('data-attribute-chain-id');
      $('.id_to_update_chain').val(find_each_id_will_update);

      $('#EditcondimentsBuilderModal').modal('show');

});
```

**The output of that two is this,**
[image: First Output]

**Now here in my second scenario,
When i change the value of Input number quantity, I want to stop the modal to open which the id is this.**

```
$('#EditcondimentsBuilderModal').modal();
```

My Codes for changing the quantity is this.

```
   $(document).on('change', '.changeQuantity', function() {
  // Does some stuff and logs the event to the console

      alert($(this).val());

      $("#EditcondimentsBuilderModal").modal('hide');
});
```

The output of changing quantity is working, The question is I want to have condition if i change the value of quantity modal will not show,

[image: I want to stop openning the modal.]

Answer (score 0):

Your hiding code seems ok, so it should be hiding `#EditcondimentsBuilderModal`. But then there's your `$('#edit_chainingBuild').on('click','tr.clickable-row', ...` handler that attempts to show it again on click. So it can easily result in a weird and confusing behavior, if you for example focus an input field with the mouse, before changing it (effectively triggering both handlers that is - open and close).

Consider altering the logic for either of the handlers, at least temporarily - to confirm the case.

Comment: Hi @jayarjo, So what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: So it's not possible to make other way to make a condition for that?

Comment: It is, but from the info you provide it is not clear what the structure of your document is why and when you want to open the modal.

Comment: as you can see the first scenario user is changing item, now after user done changing item, user can also can change the quantity without showing the second modal, because the second modal for the item only